# Django template filter escaping

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got a custom filter that takes a string and makes it into the appropriate attributes for the tooltip library I'm using. It worked with OpenTip, but I'm converting to using the tooltip library that's in Bootstrap.

Here's my filter:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(needs_autoescape=False, is_safe=True)
def tooltip(value, autoescape=False):
    """
        Filter to turn some text into the tag that the tooltip library uses -
        Written as a filter so we can switch from one tooltip library to
        another
    """
    if autoescape:
        esc = conditional_escape
    else:
        esc = lambda x: x
    if value is not None and len(value) > 0:
        retval = 'data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" ' +\
            'rel="tooltip" title="%s"' % esc(value)
        return mark_safe(retval)
    else:
        return ''
```

And here's where I'm using it in a template:

```
<form id="filter" name="filter" method="post"
class="form-inline">
{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="filterText">Filter Query:</label>
    <input type="text" id="current_filter" name="current_filter" value="{{current_filter}}" placeholder="Filter" class="span8"/>
    <i class="icon-question-sign"
    {{"Filters -<br>requester: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]<br>client: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]<br>approver:  [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]<br>worker: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]<br>ticket: [id]<br>status: [open]|[closed]|[hold]<br>type: [termination]|[extension]|[access]|[password]|baskets]<br>item: [name for category/item/attribute inventory]<br>since: [mm/dd/yyyy]|[yyyy-mm-dd]<br>before: [mm/dd/yyyy]|[yyyy-mm-dd]<br>All searchs are AND with comma delimiting"|tooltip}}></i>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn" value="Filter"/>
    <input id="filter_reset" type="button" name="filter_reset" class="btn" value="Clear existing filters"/>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

But the tooltip isn't processing the html, and when I go into Firebug and cut and paste the html, it looks like something is escaping it in spite of the fact that I marked it with mark_safe:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" name="filter" id="filter">
<input type="hidden" value="dpuAc9GNUQtvGG5wYzrWsG2Vpu5i7PWJ" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
    <label for="filterText">Filter Query:</label>
    <input type="text" class="span8" placeholder="Filter" value="" name="current_filter" id="current_filter">
    <i title="Filters -&lt;br&gt;requester: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]&lt;br&gt;client: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]&lt;br&gt;approver:  [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]&lt;br&gt;worker: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]&lt;br&gt;ticket: [id]&lt;br&gt;status: [open]|[closed]|[hold]&lt;br&gt;type: [termination]|[extension]|[access]|[password]|baskets]&lt;br&gt;item: [name for category/item/attribute inventory]&lt;br&gt;since: [mm/dd/yyyy]|[yyyy-mm-dd]&lt;br&gt;before: [mm/dd/yyyy]|[yyyy-mm-dd]&lt;br&gt;All searchs are AND with comma delimiting" rel="tooltip" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" class="icon-question-sign">
    </i>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn" name="btnSubmit">
    <input type="button" value="Clear existing filters" class="btn" name="filter_reset" id="filter_reset">
</form>
```

How do I get the html in that filter text into the page without the being escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was much stupider than what I thought it was - I had my `<script>` tags in the wrong order so I was getting the jQuery-UI tooltip instead of the Bootstrap tooltip, and the jQuery-UI tooltip doesn't support html.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `safe`:

```
{{"Filters -<br>requester: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]<br>client: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]<br>approver:  [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]<br>worker: [[first] [last]]|[windows_id]<br>ticket: [id]<br>status: [open]|[closed]|[hold]<br>type: [termination]|[extension]|[access]|[password]|baskets]<br>item: [name for category/item/attribute inventory]<br>since: [mm/dd/yyyy]|[yyyy-mm-dd]<br>before: [mm/dd/yyyy]|[yyyy-mm-dd]<br>All searchs are AND with comma delimiting"|safe|tooltip}}
```

Or you can try removing `esc` from your `tooltip` tag.

**Edit:**

I just realized what you are trying to do. <strike>You cannot put html inside a [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) in bootstrap, it's a plaintext feature only</strike>. `data-html="true"` allows it to contain html content. You can also use [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers). Above `safe` filter should still be used in order to disable html escaping.

Comment: The documentation for tooltip says that it *can* use html. Somebody else has a fiddle that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/200/ So it's django screwing it up.

Comment: You are right, it can contain html with `data-html="true"`. Then all you have to do is mark that html content as safe and it won't be escaped by django.

Comment: Just figured out what was going wrong, and boy is my face red. Look at my answer.